# ¿Como invierto palabra por palabra con arreglos?

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, ya que necesito que mi cadena introducida se invierta por palabras. Ejemplo "Hola todos" que sea "aloh sodot". Pero no se como lograr eso, use la funcion reverse que un amigo me sugirio pero solo hace "sodot aloh".

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(){
 
 string *cadena = new string();
 string frase;
 cout<<"Ingresa una cadena: "<<endl;
 getline(cin, frase);

 reverse(frase.begin(), frase.end());
 cout<<frase<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución rápida:

Almacena la línea en un *stream* para, a continuación, leer los datos del *stream* palabra a palabra. Ya solo queda invertir la palabra e imprimirla:

```
std::stringstream stream(frase);
std::string palabra;

bool first = true;
while( stream >> palabra )
{
  if( !first || (first = false) ) std::cout << ' ';

  std::reverse(palabra.begin(), palabra.end());
  std::cout << palabra;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Haz un `split` con el espacio para crear un arreglo de palabras

   ```
   "hola todos" = ["hola","todos"]
   ```
2. Recorre el arreglo y reemplaza cada posición con su palabra invertida

   ```
   ["aloh","sodot"]
   ```
3. Recorre el arreglo y concatena las palabras invertidas en un nuevo `string` agregándoles su espacio.

   ```
   "aloh sodot"
   ```